# MYSQL Loop variable inside query

Tags: mysql

I have a list of IDs that I want to Loop through the query below. So I want the query to run for each ID and have ID_FROM_LIST pull the next ID out of LIST_OF_IDS.

List:

```
LIST_OF_IDS = (379, 517, 519, 797, 800, 896, 897, 900, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 919)
```

Query:

```
    select w.Record_Count, w.Distinct_Provider_Count from  
(select  c as Record_Count, dc as Distinct_Provider_Count
from
(select * from centene_cic_decodes where standard_use in ('','P','PL')) r left join
(
select 
deceased_status as t, count(*) as c , count(distinct group_key) as dc,  'provider_status' as cat
from t_conditioncodes_0086252_cen_idvf2 
where NET_ID_ef = ID_FROM_LIST
group by 1 
union all 
select 
name_status  as t, count(*) as c , count(distinct group_key) as dc,  'name_status' as cat
from t_conditioncodes_0086252_cen_idvf2  
where NET_ID_ef = ID_FROM_LIST
group by 1
) z
on (if((z.t is null or z.t = ''), 'BLANK',z.t)) = r.Status_Codes and z.cat = r.Category 
order by r.category_rank, r.rank)w ;
```

The goal is to create a separate output for each ID. So one report for 379 then a separate one for 517 etc...

(This is just a snippet of the full query and list of IDs for simplicity.)

Comment: you have from without closing the select ...and what do you men loop variable inside query ... sql qhery don't have loop ... eventually plsql have loop .. explain better your goal .. and check for your code ..

Comment: I mean have the query run over and over, substituting the next ID each time.

Answer (score 0):

If all ids of the LIST_OF_IDS are referenced in a table, you can loop over a comma separated list (ex: "1,2,3") with find_in_set like that :

```
select t.id id_from_list
from mytable t
where find_in_set(t.id, LIST_OF_IDS);
```